# Types of attacks outside of AppSec and Vendor-Specific Systems?

Tags: appsec, known-vulnerabilities, ddos, owasp-top-ten

I'm reading up on the OWASP Top 10 for helping me defend my web app against common "app sec"-type attacks (SQL Injection, CSRF, etc.). And in a [recent question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16731/owasp-top-10-how-about-owasp-top-1000) I was prompted to not only use OWASP Top 10 for appsec vulns, but to also list all of the applications and tools I am using as part of my architecture and cross-check them against the CVE Database, which I will do.

But then there's other types of attacks: attacks that are not appsec related (not on OWASP Top 10) nor vendor-specific (and thus in the CVE DB). **Attacks like DoS/DDoS. Where would these fit in?**

I'm looking to find a list of these "other" types of attacks; attacks my software/servers/networks might be vulnerable to but aren't listed by OWASP or CVE. I'm sure there's too many to enumerate, but somewhere, *someone* has to have them aggregated into a list...thanks in advance.

Comment: A lot of DoS attacks are in the CVE database - where there is a specific DoS vulnerability in an app/OS etc. But your point has merit - I can't think of an all-encompassing list off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [CAPEC-1000](http://capec.mitre.org/data/graphs/1000.html), a very large list of attack mechanisms. Click "Expand All" to see them all.

Not all of these mechanisms are specific to the web, but they are applicable nevertheless.